# How to pass different input to a class function

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have two different classes in Django rest framework who do exact same thing but with different data. Access to that data variable is only inside a specific function. 
Currently I have explicitly writing two separate classes. How can I consolidate it into one class and inherit from it by just passing a separate argument.

```
from rest_framework import permissions
class CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool1(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in ('POST', 'PUT','PATCH'):
            return self.request.user.school.id == obj.xyz.school.id  # Different !!
        else:
            return True

class CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool2(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in ('POST', 'PUT','PATCH'):
            return self.request.user.school.id == obj.mno.school.id  # Different !!
        else:
            return True
```

`obj` variable is only available inside function `has_object_permission`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? I know it's ugly but may improve:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
class CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool(permissions.BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, school_id_type):
        self.school_id_type = school_id_type
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in ('POST', 'PUT','PATCH'):
            if self.school_id_type == "xyz":
                return self.request.user.school.id == obj.xyz.school.id  # Different !!
            elif self.school_id_type == "mno":
                return self.request.user.school.id == obj.mno.school.id  # Different !!
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return True
```

Or you can use [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from operator import attrgetter

class CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool(permissions.BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, school_id_type: str):
        self.school_id_type = school_id_type
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        s_id_type = attrgetter(self.school_id_type, 'school', 'id')(obj)
        if request.method in ('POST', 'PUT','PATCH'):
            return self.request.user.school.id == s_id_type  # Different !!
        else:
            return True
```

Both ways, you need to specify what kind of return object would you like when you're calling the class like this:

```
foo = CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool(school_id_type='xyz')
# or
bar = CreateOrUpdateInSameSchool(school_id_type='mno')
```